# How to reload Volley data to get current items from json

Tags: android, rest, android-recyclerview, android-volley, swiperefreshlayout

I have this recyclerview that loads data from a server through a json api. the Data on the server will be updated frequently so i have a "swipe to refresh" in my application. I'm using volley to get the data from the server and i want to make it in such a way that, when the user swipe to refresh, volley will reload the json data from the server so that recyclerview can display the newly added items.

This is my onSwipeListener

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, 3000);
        }
    });
```

This is how volley is requesting the data

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                public ArrayList<Deal> userlist;
                public DealAdapter adapter;

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    MainActivity.userList = this.userlist;
                    userList = new JsonConverter<Deal>().
                            toArrayList(response, Deal.class);
                    Collections.reverse(userList);

                    adapter = new DealAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userList);
                    MainActivity.adapter= this.adapter;
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
```

But i can't figure out how to refresh the volley response data when onSwipeListener is called.

this is how i add the request to Queue

```
        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Add the request back to the queue.

Comment: Also, try not to do `MainActivity.adapter`... Or `MainActivity.userList` Static variables are bad

Comment: i've already added the request back to the queue.. lemme edit the code: done

Comment: i'm using MainActivity.adapter because i want to reference it in my MainActivity class. without it, it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I know that you have to reference the adapter, but that's a poor way to do it. That's my point

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are re-assigning the Activity adapter, but never setting that new adapter back onto the Activity's RecyclerView.

Sure, you have `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`, but it is not clear where that reference came from.

Similarly, the Activity's userList is empty.

```
    MainActivity.userList = this.userlist; // This is null
    userList = new JsonConverter<Deal>().     // This should have been first
            toArrayList(response, Deal.class);
```

---

So, anyways, as I was saying in the comments, static variables are really not a good way to "toss data over the Java class wall".

Let's say you have this class to handle all the Volley calls. Notice that the `Response.Listener` interface is passed as the parameter.

```
public class JsonApi {

    private Context mContext;
    private static JsonApi instance;

    private JsonApi(Context c) { this.mContext = c; }

    public static JsonApi getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) instance = new JsonApi(context);
        return instance;
    }

    public void getSomeData(Response.Listener<String> success) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, success);
        MySingleton.getInstance(this.mContext).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Now, over in the Activity or Adapter, you can get this class and re-do Volley requests whenever.

(Apologies for any typos. This is untested, but it just gives a sample of how I would layout the code).

```
public class MainActivity implements 
      SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, 
      Response.Listener<String> {

    private List<Deal> userList;
    private DealAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private JsonApi api;

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        userList.clear();
        userList.addAll(new JsonConverter<Deal>().
                toArrayList(response, Deal.class));
        Collections.reverse(userList);

        // Handle adapter updates here
        if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Start an API call to refresh data
                    api.getSomeData(MainActivity.this); 
                }
            }, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        api = JsonApi.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

        userList = new ArrayList<Deal>();
        adapter = new DealAdapter(MainActivity.this, userList);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        // set layout manager ... etc.
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        api.getSomeData(MainActivity.this); // start the first call when the activity starts

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay So this is what worked for me. I had to call StringRequest again in the OnRefreshListener with new variable so that when the user swipes, volley requests the json data again and pass it to the adapter as shown below.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        StringRequest mrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                    public ArrayList<Deal> userlist;
                                    public DealAdapter adapter;

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        MainActivity.userList = this.userlist;
                                        userList = new JsonConverter<Deal>().
                                                toArrayList(response, Deal.class);
                                        Collections.reverse(userList);

                                        adapter = new DealAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userList);
                                        MainActivity.adapter= this.adapter;
                                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went wrong: " + "'" + error + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                });

                        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(mrequest);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                }, 3000);
        }
    });
```